# Error 0 when using ftplib

Tags: python, ftplib

I am trying to download files using python's ftplib and I am running in an issue.  When I run the script on my computer I am getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ftp_get.py", line 20, in <module>
    ftps.retrbinary('RETR '+ filename, file.write)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 710, in retrbinary
    conn.unwrap()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 771, in unwrap
    s = self._sslobj.shutdown()
socket.error: [Errno 0] Error
```

But when I run it on a server, it works flawlessly.  It also worked on my computer earlier this morning but now I get the error.  Python code below:

```
from ftplib import FTP_TLS
import os
import glob

user = "something"
passwd = "some_password"
ftps = FTP_TLS('domain')
ftps.login(user, passwd)
ftps.prot_p()       
filenames = ftps.nlst() 

for filename in filenames:
    local_filename = os.path.join('C:\\test2\\', filename)
    file = open(local_filename, 'wb')
    ftps.retrbinary('RETR '+ filename, file.write)
    print "Downloading - " + filename
    #ftps.delete (filename)
    #print "Deleting - " + filename
    file.close()

ftps.quit()
```

Why does it work on some computers and not others?

Comment: you should check if  any other program using the same port

Comment: How would I check to see if something running on port 21 or whatever port is being used?

Comment: what operating system you are using normally 21 shouldnt be used i think

Comment: MY ftp server is hosted by Yahoo.  I am trying to run my python script from a  Windows 7 computer and a Windows 2012 R2 server.

Comment: I was able to run the script this morning but currently I get the error.

Comment: use resource monitor to see if any other program using port 21 and check if your ftp server is running on yahoo

Comment: I followed the advice from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321915/ftplib-socket-error-during-after-list-ssl-sslobj-shutdown-connection-ti  and I get no error

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a problem with accessing Pure-FTPd servers.  It is documented here: https://bugs.python.org/issue25437  According to the report, there is a compatibility mode that you can set for the server.  I didn't have access to the server in my case, so commented out `ftps.prot_p()`, which means that the data is send unencrypted.

Comment: It's sad that this appears to have been fixed for Python 3.6, but apparently not for any previous versions as the ability for FTP servers to exhibit this behavior is considered a "new feature".  Disabling encryption is not an option.

Comment: I'm using python 3.8 but facing the same issue.